# Catch exception of Json unknown fields

Tags: java, json, exception

colleagues! I'm using quakus and need to catch exceptions that occurs when I send request with wrong fields (FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES = true) and send it to the response . How Can I do this? Maybe I need to write custom deserializer of this object?

Comment: What exactly is the desired content of the response ? The list of bad fields or just an error mesage ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I would like to display a list of invalid fields. Although I also can send only error message instead of invalid fields. I suppose it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, that's right, I would like to display a list of invalid fields

OK, so here's what you can do ...

1. You receive the request body as a `String`
2. Then you try to deserealise it into an object using an `ObjectMapper` class in your controller.
3. Then you need to catch the thrown exception and parse out the list of fields either from its fields (if they are there) or from the message.

See an example of an error message [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/10/jackson-json-parsing-error-unrecognizedpropertyexception-unrecognized-field-not-marked-ignorable-solved.html). Also check the [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/UnrecognizedPropertyException.html) for the `UnrecognizedPropertyException`

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Yes, that's a case, you're right, but if I have to receive the request body as an object...Is there any way for this case?

Comment: Would be very hard. You'd have to write a custom servlet filter or change the way processing of these inputs are done by Quarkus. The method above seems to be the best from the point of view of maintainability.

Comment: Arthur, it works, thank you! But I see only one wrong field inside of exception message. Do we have any json functionality to catch info about all wrong input fields?

Comment: According to the link above it should show all bad fields.